# Huawei Core NFC on watch different than Huawei Core NFC on phones?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, mobile-development, huawei-developers

I have a question regarding the Huawei core of Huawei Watch 4 and the one on Huawei Phones, without any Google services.
As it is known, Cuvre supports contactless payments on phones through it's app feature, Curve Pay or through Huawei Wallet.
Although there is no app for the watch.
Different banks around the world have made an app for their customers to use on Huawei phones for contactless payments.

There is a forum where users discussed about this.
Check the two posts in the pastelink

A user said that contactless payments through Curve Pay worked, when he used an older version of curve apk file directly from Hauwei App Gallery. I asked him and he said he couldn't remember which version it was. He said he reset the watch and didn't expect that the newer version Curve Pay wouldn't work on it. The user says that something is missing from the watch core.
Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to get the apk files that were uploaded to Huawei App Gallery (from 2022-2023) or any archive similar to apkmirror or apkpure.
I read online from Curve saying that there are few complexities coming from HMS core (for them to build an app for the watch) but my question is how HMS core on Huawei Watch 4 different from HMS core on Huawei Phones? If many different bank apps with contactless payments work on the watch, then what complexities are they talking about?

Links of videos-examples of people using/sideloaded bank apps of their countries on Huawei Watch 4 and made contactless payments in the pastebin

There is also a bank in my country that has it's own contactless payments app for Huawei phones, but when it was sideloaded on Huawei Watch, it would give a weird message and then close.
I'm not sure what that message means or how to bypass it. It says " Please uncheck this option to disable foreground notifications"

A user from that forum, used APK mod and modified  (so would not show that message) but I'd prefer if I do that on my own rather than use someone's else apk file (for safety).
I'm not sure how he did that, so I can do it myself.

I included all the links in a pastebin because it wouldn't allow me to post many links here

https://justpaste.it/47qf3